# Issue with quoting of IS, NULL, NOT, !, and other reserved strings in ON conditions of JOIN clauses in Zend Framework 2

Tags: sql, join, zend-framework2, quoting, zend-db-select

I have an SQL statement, that selets sport classes/courses (`courses`) with their trainers (`trainers`) over an association table (`courses_trainers`). Since some courses have multiple trainers, I use the `GROUP_CONCAT(...)` function to get the trainer names into one field.  Some trainers rows are empty or `NULL`, so I add a `trainers.name IS NOT NULL` and a `trainers.name != ""` condition to the `ON` clause of the trainers `JOIN`:

**`SQL` statement**

```
SELECT
    courses.id AS id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT trainers.name SEPARATOR "|||") AS trainers
    ...
FROM
    courses
    ...
LEFT JOIN
    courses_trainers ON courses.id = courses_trainers.course_id
LEFT JOIN
    trainers ON trainer_id = trainers.id
    AND trainers.name IS NOT NULL
    AND trainers.name != ""
    ...
...
WHERE `courses`.`id` = '898'
GROUP BY
    courses.id
;
```

**OO variant in the `CourseTable` class**

```
public function findOnceByID($id) { 
    $concatDelimiter = self::CONCAT_DELIMITER;
    $select = new Select();
    ...
    $select->columns(array(
        'id', ...
    ));
    $select->from($this->tableGateway->getTable());
    $select
        ...
        ->join('courses_trainers', 'courses.id = courses_trainers.course_id', array(), Select::JOIN_LEFT)
        ->join('trainers', 'trainer_id = trainers.id AND trainers.name IS NOT NULL AND trainers.name != ""', array(
            'trainers' => new Expression('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT trainers.name SEPARATOR "' . $concatDelimiter . '")')
            ), Select::JOIN_LEFT)
        ...
    ;
    $where
        ->equalTo('courses.id', $id)
    ;
    $select->where($where, Predicate::OP_AND);
    $select->group('courses.id');
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
    return $resultSet;
}
```

The generated `JOIN` code I get looks like this:

```
LEFT JOIN
    `courses_trainers` ON `courses`.`id` = `courses_trainers`.`course_id`
LEFT JOIN
    `trainers` ON `trainer_id` = `trainers`.`id`
    AND `trainers`.`name` `IS` `NOT` `NULL`
    AND `trainers`.`name` `!`= `"``"`
```

So, here is to much quoted.

How to "explain" to the ZF, that `IS`, `NOT`, `"` etc. should not be quoted?

Comment: have your tried making the ON clause an expression? ie `->join('trainers', new Expression('trainer_id = trainers.id AND trainers.name IS NOT NULL AND trainers.name != ""'), `

Comment: Oh nooo! So much effort (I've actually spent hours to resolve the issue) and the solution is so easy! :) It works! And is much more  elegant, than my solution! Please create an answer from your comment, in order I can accept it.

Comment: Ouch! Have to admit I wasn't 100% sure it would work as it seemed too easy considering the work you'd gone to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `join` method accepts an expression as its second parameter for the `ON` clause

```
->join('trainers', new Expression('trainer_id = trainers.id AND trainers.name IS NOT NULL AND trainers.name != ""'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Responsible for quoting is [`Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\PlatformInterface#quoteIdentifierInFragment(...)`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Platform/PlatformInterface.php#L93) (or more precise its implementations, in this case in [`Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Platform/Mysql.php#L187)), that gets as second argument an array of "safe words". `Zend\Db\Sql\Select#processJoins(...)` [passes](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php#L751) to it the `array('=', 'AND', 'OR', '(', ')', 'BETWEEN', '<', '>')`. As `IS`, `NOT`, `!` etc. are not in the list, they are quoted.

The solution is to extend the `Zend\Db\Sql\Select` and overwrire its [`processJoins(...)`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Select.php#L712), adding the additional "safe words" needed to the list of the second argument in the `quoteIdentifierInFragment(...)` call:

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\Db\Sql;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\DriverInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\StatementContainerInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\ParameterContainer;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\PlatformInterface;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select as ZendSelect;

class Select extends ZendSelect
{

    ...

    protected function processJoins(PlatformInterface $platform, DriverInterface $driver = null, ParameterContainer $parameterContainer = null)
    {
        ...
        // process joins
        $joinSpecArgArray = array();
        foreach ($this->joins as $j => $join) {
            ...
            $joinSpecArgArray[$j][] = ($join['on'] instanceof ExpressionInterface)
                ? $this->processExpression($join['on'], $platform, $driver, $this->processInfo['paramPrefix'] . 'join' . ($j+1) . 'part')
                : $platform->quoteIdentifierInFragment($join['on'], array('=', 'AND', 'OR', '(', ')', 'BETWEEN', '<', '>', '!', 'IS', 'NULL', 'NOT', '"')); // on
            ...
        }

        return array($joinSpecArgArray);
    }

    ...

}
```