# Use of a mysql function in the 'ON' clause of a mysql JOIN query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I need to join two tables where a substring of the base table's join column's value is used to join with the other table.

I'm using zend framework 2 and I've written the query as follows.

```
$select = new Select($this->table);

$select->columns(array('match_code'))
           ->join('countries','countries.cid = SUBSTR(matches.teams,1,3)', 'name')
           ->where(array('round'=>1));
```

This gives an error.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1630 FUNCTION mydatabase.SUBSTR does not exist. 
Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual
```

I've run the mysql query corresponds to this and it works perfectly.

```
SELECT `matches`.`match_code`, `countries`.`name` 
FROM `matches` INNER JOIN `countries` 
ON `countries`.`cid`=SUBSTR(`matches`.`teams`,1,3) 
WHERE `round` = 1
```

I cannot use `Zend\Db\Sql\Expression` in here as the `join()` expects only a string.

Any suggestions??

Comment: `I cannot use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression in here as the join() expects only a string.`. Are you sure? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060679/issue-with-quoting-of-is-null-not-and-other-reserved-strings-in-on-conditi/16062109#16062109

Comment: It seems like I've made a mistake here. I tried to use the Expression for a part of the ON clause... This must work. Thanks @Crisp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using `Zend\Db\Sql\Expression` in the `ON` clause of `join()`.

```
$select->columns(array('match_code'))
           ->join('countries',new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('countries.cid = SUBSTR(matches.teams,1,3)'), 'name')
           ->where(array('round'=>1));
```

Thanks to @Crisp for the suggestion.